# Ruby Google Cloud PubSub async pull returns GRPC::DeadlineExceeded error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grpc, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

Hi I have a subscription set up in Google PubSub and I am trying to pull messages asynchronously using the "official" **[google-cloud-ruby](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby)** library. Here is my code which will be executed from a rake task which passes in `subscription_name`:

```
def pull!
  creds = Google::Cloud::PubSub::Credentials.new(
    GCP_CREDENTIALS_KEYFILE_PATH,
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub"
  )
  messages = []
  pubsub = Google::Cloud::PubSub.new(
    project_id: GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
    credentials: creds
  )

  subscription = pubsub.subscription(subscription_name)

  subscription.pull(immediate: true).each do |received_message|
    puts "Received message: #{received_message.data}"
    received_message.acknowledge!
    messages.push(received_message)
  end

  # Return the collected messages
  messages
  
rescue => error
  Rails.logger error

  messages.presence
end
```

The `Google::Cloud::PubSub::Credentials` part references a working keyfile. I know the JSON keyfile is good since I can use it to generate a working Bearer token using `oauth2l` and pull from the PubSub using cURL, postman, Net::HTTP, etc. Using the same JSON credentials for a separate `Google::Cloud::Storage` service and that works fine also.

But for some reason using `Google::Cloud::PubSub` it just hangs and won't respond. After about 60 seconds I get the following error:

```
GRPC::DeadlineExceeded: 4:Deadline Exceeded. debug_error_string:{"created":"@1602610740.445195000","description":"Deadline Exceeded","file":"src/core/ext/filters/deadline/deadline_filter.cc","file_line":69,"grpc_status":4}
/Users/bbulpet/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grpc-1.32.0-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/active_call.rb:29:in `check_status'
/Users/bbulpet/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grpc-1.32.0-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/active_call.rb:180:in `attach_status_results_and_complete_call'
/Users/bbulpet/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grpc-1.32.0-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/active_call.rb:376:in `request_response'
/Users/bbulpet/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grpc-1.32.0-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/client_stub.rb:172:in `block (2 levels) in request_response'
/Users/bbulpet/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grpc-1.32.0-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/interceptors.rb:170:in `intercept!'
/Users/bbulpet/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/grpc-1.32.0-universal-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/client_stub.rb:171:in `block in request_response'
/Users/bbulpet/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gapic-common-0.3.4/lib/gapic/grpc/service_stub/rpc_call.rb:121:in `call'
/Users/bbulpet/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gapic-common-0.3.4/lib/gapic/grpc/service_stub.rb:156:in `call_rpc'
/Users/bbulpet/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/google-cloud-pubsub-v1-0.1.2/lib/google/cloud/pubsub/v1/subscriber/client.rb:503:in `get_subscription'
/Users/bbulpet/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/google-cloud-pubsub-2.1.0/lib/google/cloud/pubsub/service.rb:154:in `get_subscription'
/Users/bbulpet/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/google-cloud-pubsub-2.1.0/lib/google/cloud/pubsub/project.rb:286:in `subscription'
```

Adding a debugger shows that the following line is what hangs and results in an error:

```
subscription = pubsub.subscription(subscription_name)
```

I've tried everything I can think of based on the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/Google/Cloud/PubSub.html). Updated all related gems and even tried using deprecated syntax out of desparation. If anyone has at least an idea of where to start that would be most appreciated, thanks!

### UPDATE

So it turns out that for some reason running this locally was not able to connect, but when shipped to a deployed environment the above code connected flawlessly to pubsub and was able to pull and ack messages. Further, upon making the initial connection in the deployed environment, I am now able to connect locally as well using the same credentials.

[Link to Github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/7951) conversation for context around the troubleshooting process and quartzmo suggestion to try deploying to another environment.

Comment: Glad to hear that the issue got resolved deploying to another environment! I believe it would be great if you could post your last update in the answers section so that the community may benefit from it in case they experience the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you still having this issue? I just tried to reproduce it using Ruby 2.6.5p114, google-cloud-pubsub 2.1.0 and grpc 1.32.0 (same versions as you), but I cannot reproduce it. Here is my code (slightly modified to run in a Minitest spec context) for comparison:

```
  GCP_CREDENTIALS_KEYFILE_PATH = "/Users/quartzmo/my-project.json"
  GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID = "my-project-id"

  def pull! topic_name, subscription_name
    creds = Google::Cloud::PubSub::Credentials.new(
      GCP_CREDENTIALS_KEYFILE_PATH,
      scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub"
    )
    messages = []
    pubsub = Google::Cloud::PubSub.new(
      project_id: GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
      credentials: creds
    )
    topic = pubsub.create_topic topic_name
    topic.subscribe subscription_name

    topic.publish "A test message from #{topic_name} to #{subscription_name}"
  
    subscription = pubsub.subscription(subscription_name)
  
    subscription.pull(immediate: true).each do |received_message|
      puts "Received message: #{received_message.data}"
      received_message.acknowledge!
      messages.push(received_message)
    end
  
    # Return the collected messages
    messages
  end

  focus
  it "pull!" do
    topic_name = random_topic_name
    subscription_name = random_subscription_name
    messages = pull! topic_name, subscription_name
    assert_equal 1, messages.count
    assert_equal "A test message from #{topic_name} to #{subscription_name}", messages[0].data
  end
```

And this is the output:

```
% bundle exec rake test
Run options: --junit --junit-filename=sponge_log.xml --seed 30984

# Running:

Received message: A test message from ruby-pubsub-samples-test-topic-7cb10bde to ruby-pubsub-samples-test-subscription-f47f2eaa
.

Finished in 6.529219s, 0.1532 runs/s, 0.3063 assertions/s.

1 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

**Update (2020-10-20):** This issue was resolved when executing the code in a different environment, although the reason is unknown. See [comment on GitHub issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/7951#issuecomment-713016309).

Comment: quartzmo Thanks so much for your answer. However the problem still persists. Tried your example (although it would throw a permissions error since this account cannot create topics) but still getting the `GRPC::DeadlineExceeded: 4:Deadline Exceeded` error after a minute hang time on `pubsub.create_topic`. In other words, this error is returned any time `pubsub.anything` is called. Found a similar issue with the Python library (github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/9390). Digging into that looks like a sort of type mismatch going on with gapic connection. Not sure if this is related.

Comment: Are you able to test using another account with full (or broader) permissions in the same environment?

Comment: Well this is the only service account our team has access to. But that said, I can easily and quickly retrieve messages from this subscription using both cURL and Net:HTTP with the same credentials and the `https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project-name/subscriptions/subscription-name:pull` endpoint. So this account does have the requisite permission to `pull`. Our subscription itself was set up in the GCP GUI. Would there be a difference in accessing that subscription VS one that is created as you've shown above?

Comment: Can you create/obtain another service account for testing in this environment, and try running my adaptation of your example? It would be great to eliminate auth and permissions issues before looking deeper into the library.

Comment: I can try to create a ticket for a new service account but it will likely be rejected per our policies regarding access to GCP services, but I will try. In the meantime the application is able to pull messages with Net::HTTP so perhaps google-cloud-pubsub is not the best option for this use case.

Comment: The gcloud client offers another way to test the credentials and permissions. Are you able to use `gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull` in that environment with the same service account? (See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#authorizing_with_a_service_account)

Comment: There's an SO warning about extended discussions, lets move this discussion to https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/7951